# ipython shows invalid syntax when running from terminal

Tags: python, syntax, ipython

I use python 3.7 but also 3.6 and 2.7 are installed, I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

I changed the order of python to python 2.7 still not working, I am using it on VMware. I guess I made changes to python3, I installed many packages.

I'm trying to run jupyter notebook, but I can't figure out what could cause the problem.

When I try to run ipython from the terminal its shows:

```
stealth@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ ipython
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/stealth/.local/bin/ipython", line 7, in <module>
    from IPython import start_ipython
  File "/home/stealth/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 55, in <module>
    from .core.application import Application
  File "/home/stealth/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/application.py", line 25, in <module>
    from IPython.core import release, crashhandler
  File "/home/stealth/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/crashhandler.py", line 27, in <module>
    from IPython.core import ultratb
  File "/home/stealth/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 116, in <module>
    from IPython.utils import path as util_path
  File "/home/stealth/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/utils/path.py", line 17, in <module>
    from IPython.utils.process import system
  File "/home/stealth/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/utils/process.py", line 19, in <module>
    from ._process_posix import system, getoutput, arg_split, check_pid
  File "/home/stealth/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/utils/_process_posix.py", line 23, in <module>
    import pexpect
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pexpect/__init__.py", line 75, in <module>
    from .pty_spawn import spawn, spawnu
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pexpect/pty_spawn.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .spawnbase import SpawnBase
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pexpect/spawnbase.py", line 218
    def expect(self, pattern, timeout=-1, searchwindowsize=-1, async=False):
                                                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`async` has become a reserved keyword starting from Python 3.7, so you have to upgrade your `pexpect` package.

You can run `sudo python3.7 -m pip install --upgrade pexpect`. If you still encounter the same error, try removing possibly conflicting versions using `sudo apt-get remove python-pexpect python3-pexpect`.

Comment: I used the first command, it said command pip3.7 nor found,I tried 2.7 instead,also not found, I used just pip it upgraded but still the same error when runing Ipython

Comment: can you maybe please help me via teamwork when is possible ?

Comment: Can you please add the output of `apt list --installed | grep "pexpect"` ?

Comment: stealth@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ apt list --installed | grep "pexpect"

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

python-pexpect/xenial,now 4.0.1-1 all [installed,automatic]
python3-pexpect/xenial,now 4.0.1-1 all [installed]

Comment: Did you try the second command (to remove unwanted `pexpect` conflicting versions)? Alternatively try also running `python3.7 -m pip install --upgrade pexpect`

Comment: Or even `python3 -m pip install --upgrade pexpect`

Comment: well, I tried the new command with -m,it woked, the upgrade has worked already , then I tried the remove anyway, and it works...for now at least...thank you so much